# Calling UITableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath: for just one iteration

Tags: iphone, uitableview

When attempting to create a form with UITextFields, it appears that cellForRowAtIndexPath: gets called every time a user scrolls up and down the tableView. When this happens, a new UITextField is created, and the old UITextFields are no longer visible. Is there a way for the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to be called for just one iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create UITableViewCell nibs in Interface Builder with UITextFields and link all of the objects with the viewController class.

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs for `UITableViewCell`, especially [A Closer Look at Table-View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html) and the section about static cell content.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might consider a simple UIScrollView rather than a UITableView? It's difficult to tell what you're trying to accomplish here. Perhaps add a bit more detail to your question.

Comment: Agreed... one should never use a tableview for a scrolling form really...its not what they were designed for.